# Can't sync tomdroid and tomboy notes!

Tags: sync, tomboy, notes

I am pretty sure there are a lot of thread regarding this and I read most of them, still I can't sync tom boy notes from my laptop to my tomdroid. I tried setting up a rainy server and when ever I try to connect it says server busy. I tried using the public servers provided by tomdroid, and they don't work too. HELP!
Also, everpad doesn't work. I was able to install but can't edit notes. so it is pretty usesless. 
If there are any note taking apps that can sync to my android phone, please suggest. I use ubuntu 15.10

Answer (score 0):

You can also use, [Simplenote](https://github.com/Automattic/simplenote-electron/releases/download/v1.0.3/simplenote-1.0.3.deb) or even Google Keep through Google Chrome.

Hope I've helped.

PS: There's also a new app around named [Turtl](https://turtlapp.com/), and is pretty good too.